# Error on Jupyter Notebook in Anaconda Env. - "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _iterative: The specified module could not be found."

Tags: python, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, scipy, anaconda

I am using Anaconda Environment and installed a Jupyter Notebook for deep learning. I tried importing:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedKFold
from sklearn.model_selection import KFold
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
```

And this error shows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[2], line 1
----> 1 from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
      2 from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix, classification_report
      3 from keras.wrappers.scikit_learn import KerasClassifier

File ~\anaconda3\envs\intel_dl_en\lib\site-packages\sklearn\__init__.py:82
     80 from . import _distributor_init  # noqa: F401
     81 from . import __check_build  # noqa: F401
---> 82 from .base import clone
     83 from .utils._show_versions import show_versions
     85 __all__ = [
     86     "calibration",
     87     "cluster",
   (...)
    128     "show_versions",
    129 ]

File ~\anaconda3\envs\intel_dl_en\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py:17
     15 from . import __version__
     16 from ._config import get_config
---> 17 from .utils import _IS_32BIT
     18 from .utils._set_output import _SetOutputMixin
     19 from .utils._tags import (
     20     _DEFAULT_TAGS,
     21 )

File ~\anaconda3\envs\intel_dl_en\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py:17
     15 import warnings
     16 import numpy as np
---> 17 from scipy.sparse import issparse
     19 from .murmurhash import murmurhash3_32
     20 from .class_weight import compute_class_weight, compute_sample_weight

File ~\anaconda3\envs\intel_dl_en\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\__init__.py:283
    278 from ._arrays import (
    279     csr_array, csc_array, lil_array, dok_array, coo_array, dia_array, bsr_array
    280 )
    282 # For backward compatibility with v0.19.
--> 283 from . import csgraph
    285 # Deprecated namespaces, to be removed in v2.0.0
    286 from . import (
    287     base, bsr, compressed, construct, coo, csc, csr, data, dia, dok, extract,
    288     lil, sparsetools, sputils
    289 )

File ~\anaconda3\envs\intel_dl_en\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\__init__.py:185
    157 __docformat__ = "restructuredtext en"
    159 __all__ = ['connected_components',
    160            'laplacian',
    161            'shortest_path',
   (...)
    182            'csgraph_to_masked',
    183            'NegativeCycleError']
--> 185 from ._laplacian import laplacian
    186 from ._shortest_path import (
    187     shortest_path, floyd_warshall, dijkstra, bellman_ford, johnson,
    188     NegativeCycleError
    189 )
    190 from ._traversal import (
    191     breadth_first_order, depth_first_order, breadth_first_tree,
    192     depth_first_tree, connected_components
    193 )

File ~\anaconda3\envs\intel_dl_en\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\csgraph\_laplacian.py:7
      5 import numpy as np
      6 from scipy.sparse import isspmatrix
----> 7 from scipy.sparse.linalg import LinearOperator
     10 ###############################################################################
     11 # Graph laplacian
     12 def laplacian(
     13     csgraph,
     14     normed=False,
   (...)
     21     symmetrized=False,
     22 ):

File ~\anaconda3\envs\intel_dl_en\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\__init__.py:120
      1 """
      2 Sparse linear algebra (:mod:`scipy.sparse.linalg`)
      3 ==================================================
   (...)
    117 
    118 """
--> 120 from ._isolve import *
    121 from ._dsolve import *
    122 from ._interface import *

File ~\anaconda3\envs\intel_dl_en\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_isolve\__init__.py:4
      1 "Iterative Solvers for Sparse Linear Systems"
      3 #from info import __doc__
----> 4 from .iterative import *
      5 from .minres import minres
      6 from .lgmres import lgmres

File ~\anaconda3\envs\intel_dl_en\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\linalg\_isolve\iterative.py:9
      6 from textwrap import dedent
      7 import numpy as np
----> 9 from . import _iterative
     11 from scipy.sparse.linalg._interface import LinearOperator
     12 from .utils import make_system

ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _iterative: The specified module could not be found.
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling Scipy on my environment but didn't work. Other libraries such as Pandas, tensorflow, numpy did work and were imported properly. I'm not sure where this problem is rooted from. I also experienced this on matplotlib and seaborn. I am using python 3.9.16.